# Stock price data - current and historical - paid/free

Tags: php, api, finance, stock

There are countless questions asking where you can get reliable stock data for a commercial app for free but this seems a pretty hopeless task. Does anyone know anywhere it can be found for a reasonable price?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you may not consider these prices to be reasonable but you can check out [xignite](http://www.xignite.com/product/global-stock-quote-data/). [BATS](http://www.batstrading.com/market_data/products/) sells its last sale feed for $25K per month for external distribution. In general there is no feed that is cheap that will enable you to redistribute it.